# How to set multiple items as selected in JList using setSelectedValue?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jlist

I have a jList that is populated dynamically by adding to the underlying listModel. Now if I have three Strings whose value I know and I do

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    jList.setSelectedValue(obj[i],true);//true is for shouldScroll or not
}
```

only the last item appears to be selected...If this can't be done and I have to set the selection from the underlying model how should I go about it???

Also please note the jList has selection mode:

```
  jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Although [StanislasV answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961343/how-to-set-multiple-items-as-selected-in-jlist-using-setselectedvalue/5961398#5961398) is perfectly valid, i would prefer to avoid adding one selection interval to another. Instead, you should prefer to call the `JList` associated [`ListSelectionModel#setSelectionInterval(int, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29) method like this :

```
jList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(0, 3)
```

If you want your list selection to be disjoint, you'll moreover have to write your own [`ListSelectionModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html).

Comment: -1 that's simply wrong - addSelectionInterval is _the_ method intended to .. well .. adding something to the selection. The exact outcome depends on the SelectionMode

Answer (score 10):

Note that all xxSelectedValue methods are convenience wrapper methods around the selectionModel (which supports index-based selection access only) on the JList. Setting multiple selections *per value* is not supported. If you really want it, you'll have to implement a convenience method yourself. Basically, you'll have to loop over the model's elements until you find the corresponding indices and call the index-based methods, something like:

```
public void setSelectedValues(JList list, Object... values) {
    list.clearSelection();
    for (Object value : values) {
        int index = getIndex(list.getModel(), value);
        if (index >=0) {
            list.addSelectionInterval(index, index);
        }
    }
    list.ensureIndexIsVisible(list.getSelectedIndex());
}

public int getIndex(ListModel model, Object value) {
    if (value == null) return -1;
    if (model instanceof DefaultListModel) {
        return ((DefaultListModel) model).indexOf(value);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
        if (value.equals(model.getElementAt(i))) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: +1 `addSelectionInterval` does the trick. This should be the accepted accept!!!! :D

Comment: Get in mind that DefaultListModel.indexOf(value) already do a linear search so it's the same using indexOf than the for version (the same efficiency although more readable).

Comment: @PhoneixS it's an implementation detail that we can't know :)

Comment: We can really know, at least with oracle and OpenJDK as we can see the source code (like I have done). It's the good thing about OpenSource :D

Comment: @PhoneixS yeah, we could read - but we can't know for sure because the implementation isn't part of the specification and could change without notice :) Don't rely on implementation details, never-ever ...

Comment: @kleopatra I totally agree, but it's something to get in mind so you don't think that `indexOf` is somewhat magic.

Answer (score 3):

```
jList.addSelectionInterval(0,2);
```

Comment: +1 spot-on with `addSelectionInterval`, but in order for this to be a truly useful answer, an explanation is required.